# To assign var to name attribute of input tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Here I am trying to store medicines given by doctor via html form.
By taking an input as text in cells of a dynamic table, I want to append some counter to the name tag of the input cell by using javascript but unable to do so.I want to create new input tag with attr name as prsc+counter-value
so can u please help me

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="prsc0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="prsc1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="prsc2"></td>
  </tr>
```

```
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<script>
 var counter=3;
 function myCreateFunction() {
     var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
     var row = table.insertRow(0);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     counter=counter+1;
     var presc="prsc"+""+counter;
     cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name=presc>';

 }

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you're just trying to concatenate the value of `presc`, correct? Perhaps this is what you're after... `cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="'+presc+'">';`

Comment: `cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='"+presc+"'>";`

Comment: @Santi Sorry, didn't know there will be a comment already when I was writing :-)

Comment: Thank u guys.... It worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `presc` is a variable:

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="' + presc + '">';
```

or without creating it:

```
cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="presc' + counter + '">';
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nupecomozi/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM API to create the input element instead of building an HTML string:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.name = 'prsc' + counter;
cell1.appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function counter (){
     for(i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll('input').length; i++){
        document.querySelectorAll('input')[i].name=`prsc${i}`;
     }
}
```